# Does Nvidia driver have any business with Xorg configuration?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, ssh, xorg

16.04 LTS, 4.15.13-041513-generic. Finally got Nvidia 390.25 driver working. Downloaded from graphics ppa. According to the Nvidia installation guide, I should let nvidia-xconfig rewrite the Xorg.conf, but it causes The login screen loop (Secure Boot ON, you guessed it). However, after Xorg.conf being deleted, the OS starts fine. Not sure about the graphics driver working currently, but if I managed to start Maple software, it seems like Nvidia is in action.

So, I spilled liters of sweat to make the Nvidia driver work, something disturbed, whatever that was, but this time I'm shocked to know Xorg has no deal with Nvidia driver. If I'm right..?

I couldn't sign SSH keys by (read the log below)

```
-> Signing kernel module:
   executing: '"/lib/modules/4.15.13-041513-generic/build/scripts/sign-file"  "/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" "/root/.ssh/id_rsa" "./kernel/nvidia.ko"'...
   Usage: scripts/sign-file [-dp]     []
          scripts/sign-file -s     []
   executing: '"/lib/modules/4.15.13-041513-generic/build/scripts/sign-file" "sha512" "/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" "/root/.ssh/id_rsa" "./kernel/nvidia.ko"'...
   At main.c:163:
   - SSL error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line: pem_lib.c:701
   sign-file: /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: Success
-> Failed to sign kernel module.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

Yes, I had to download the .run file for the same driver version. Or I didn't, I was just in a hurry to complete the damn mission.

Anyway, Xorg conf deleted == tout va bien. Question's remaining: should I give a **** (put in whatever suits you, it's your fantasy)? Read helluva many threads around the net and didn't find a working solution. Would appreciate the explanation.

Comment: To address the title of your question itself and, not the fine details inside, yes nVidia updates xorg with particulars for such things as screen tearing and whatnot.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Even when Xorg.conf doesn't exist by default? I actually summoned it by X -configuration, and then nvidia-xconfig to make changes. Then, Ubuntu didn't start up

Comment: Always wondered, why do you people give answers in the comments? Is it the most convenient place to leave any kind of response? And read them too?

Comment: I use comments when I don't have a perfect answer, or only part of an answer. I also use comments to seek clarification or to recommend a place the OP can look for additional information. If an answer is inferior and more of a comment, it can get down-voted and deleted.